# Django - Manipulating list of lists in view

Tags: django

I have function in model, which returns a list of lists - 
[[a1,a2],[b1,b2]].I am passing this to view.But, how do I access each value.I want to display a1,a2,b1 and b2 separately.

Answer (score 4):

```
{% for item in mylist %}
  {{item.0}}<br />
  {{item.1}}
{% endfor %}
```

should display

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
```

Comment: Should be {{item.0}}. | is used for applying filters.